# How do I check 'T for types not being allowed to be null?

Tags: reflection, f#, null, nullable

given

```
let inline deserialize<'t> x :'t option = 
    printfn "Attempting to deserialize %A" typeof<'t>.Name
    try
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'t>(x)
        |> Some
    with ex ->
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(sprintf "Error deserialization failed:%s" ex.Message)
        None
```

is returning for example an `obj list` as `null`. `FSharpList<_>` is not allowed to be null. How can I, without knowing what `'t` is ask F# if the type I'm about to return supports `null` so that I can halt/throw/act accordingly? Is there a reflection flag or `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection...` method for this?

Answer (score 3):

The full answer involves checking if the type is a record (in which case `null` is never allowed), or if it's a union (in which case null is allowed if the type has a `CompilationRepresentation` `CustomAttribute` whose flags contain the `UseNullAsTrueValue` member (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.compilationrepresentationflags-enumeration-%5Bfsharp%5D for more details)).

To answer the first question you can use the `IsRecord` function in the `FSharpType` module (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/reflection.fsharptype-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) and to answer the second you can use a combination of the `IsUnion` function on that same module and `CustomAttribute` hunting.

In case the type is a union with `UseNullAsTrueValue` set, you should be good to go, just send the value along.

Comment: doesn't this skip F# created/defined classes which are not supposed to be null either?

Comment: Not sure I understand. As soon as you make a class it can be null. It's only F# records/unions that get the default expectation of being non-null.

Comment: classes defined in F# without the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute, will not compile if you try to set `let x : TestFClass = null` So all F# assemblies dependent on that type expect it to not be null. So class defined in F# are not supposed to be null.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I made a class in sharplab and found that the compiler does add an attribute to denote an F# class: `    [<CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)>]`

So you could look for the presence of that attribute _without_ the presence of the AllowNullLiteral attribute to be a signal that the type does not allow null.

Here's the sharplab link to the comparison: https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgPg9gDgUwHYAIDKBPCAXBBbAWAChjsNEUBhACgEoUBeYlFlPfAIwQCcVsALAJYQAdAFk6jFHWatiAbQA8AQWDAYAdwByAVzUAZQbm4BDYAD4AuqXIIUutTXoMUAY2AmIEFMgAmQA=

Comment: awesome, can you update your answer to include all parts?

Answer (score 1):

Best I can think of is to box the result (in case you are deserializing structs) and pattern match it with null:

```
  let inline deserialize<'t> x :'t option = 
      printfn "Attempting to deserialize %A" typeof<'t>.Name
      try
          let obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'t>(x)
          match box obj with
          | null -> None
          | _ -> Some obj
      with ex ->
          System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(sprintf "Error deserialization failed:%s" ex.Message)
          None

  let r1 = deserialize<obj list> ("[1,2,3]") //val r1 : obj list option = Some [1L; 2L; 3L]
  let r2 = deserialize<obj list> ("null") //val r2 : obj list option = None
```

Comment: this just checks for null, it does not check if `'t` is allowed to be null.

Comment: Not sure why would you need to check the type and not the resulting value. But I guess simple reflection should do it: `let typeCanBeNull = (not typeof<'t>.IsValueType) || (System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof<'t>) <> null);`

Comment: because if the value is allowed to be null in F# land, then it is fine if it is null, if not, then yes I would check the value is not null, and decide to throw/None/whatever I pick as the behavior for this case.